# In Mac: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command Original error: Could not find adb

Tags: android, adb, appium

While I start new session in APPIUM am getting the below error prompted in appium:

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in ["/Library/platform-tools/adb/platform-tools/adb","/Library/platform-tools/adb/emulator/adb","/Library/platform-tools/adb/tools/adb","/Library/platform-tools/adb/tools/bin/adb"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/Library/platform-tools/adb'?

Is there any solution for MacOs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you setup env variable properly.

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Set variables making sure the path is correct

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/LOCAL_PATH_TO/android-sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Verify that it is working:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

You can also install appium-doctor tool to check you got everything setup for Appium:

```
npm install appium-doctor -g
```

Check setup for Android testing

```
appium-doctor --android
```

Comment: When I start session in Appium, the error message shows ,

[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not find 'adb' in ["/Library/platform-tools/adb/platform-tools/adb","/Library/platform-tools/adb/emulator/adb","/Library/platform-tools/adb/tools/adb","/Library/platform-tools/adb/tools/bin/adb"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at '/Library/platform-tools/adb'?

Comment: does `appium-doctor --android` pass for you? You might need to open Android Studio and make sure adb is installed among components